# Bug when rendering "<" inside a <pre> tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

If I want to write something like "low < high" in a `<pre>` or `<pre><code>` tag, the rendering shows only "low", plus some wrong new line afterwards:

```
# here we are in a pre/code tag
low
```

But it works within back-ticks and with 4 spaces indentation
`low < high`  # here are backticks

```
low < hight  # here is indented
```

However "high > low" renders without problems, although the bug above keeps adding spurious new lines.

```
# here we are in a pre/code tag
hight > low
```

`high > low`  # here are backticks

```
hight > low  # here is indented
```

I'm using version 49.0.2623.108 Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128477/display-error-when-nesting-pre-in-code-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since everything in a `pre` is HTML, you have to properly escape the `<`, else it thinks it is the start of a HTML tag.

This gives the desired result:

```
<pre><code>
# here we are in a pre/code tag
low &lt; high
</code></pre>
```

Result:

```
# here we are in a pre/code tag
low < high
```

Related feature request to change this behavior (the propsal in the feature request goes against the HTML standards, where I have to agree with Shog9): [Can we have the pre tag work as the code tag does for angle brackets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32066/245360)

Comment: I see. I guess it makes sense. About the request in the link: I agree that no one should change HTML standards. However, would be possible to warn the user that there are un-matched tags or ``<``/``>`` within ``<pre><code>``?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to think that is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) and not a bug. How do you think the parser should distinguish between `<pre>foo <code>`, where you want the second `<` to be interpreted as start of an HTML tag, and `<pre>low < high`, where you want the second `<` to be escaped to `&lt;`?

When using HTML directly, you are in advanced territory; you are expected to do your escapes yourself as needed.